# Pythonic/Numpy:ic way to multiply each row of a 2D array with themselves?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array: `arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])` I want to multiply these column by column, to obtain `[1,8,27]`. Is there a numpy function to do this? I can do it by `prod = reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,arr)`, but it feels like I've missed some obvious numpy function....

Comment: are you after this: `arr**3` or `arr.prod(axis=0)` ?

Comment: arr.prod(axis=0) was exactly what I was looking for. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

```
In [64]: arr.prod(axis=0)
Out[64]: array([ 1,  8, 27])
```